# Why does Nagato have Rinnegan when he was awakened using the reanimation jutsu?

Tags: naruto

Because it was not achieved through his own blood, and was implanted by Madara, he did not have the Rinnegan when he was born.

The shinobi who are revived using Edo Tensei usually are resurrected with characteristics they have from birth.

Since he wasn't born with the Rinnegan and not really the original owner, why did he have it while he was revived using the Edo Tensei?

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up. Also, I didn't know that the age of a person to be reanimated could be controlled.

Comment: This was why Kabuto's jutsu was considered far more perfect than that of Orochimaru and The Second. It enabled him to make modifications to the resurrected and also choose the age/prime time of their life for the best result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nagato wasn't revived with the natural attributes from birth.

Kabuto's Edo Tensei revives the person with all their abilities, including the Kekkai Genkai and Kekkai Tota. Also, the revived are actually reincarnated in the physical form that they died in (here's where Madara is an exception).

If you take Madara's case, Kabuto revived him at a much younger age than he died at, gave him enhancements and also Rinnegan which shouldn't have had at that age.

He did the same for Nagato. He combined Nagato's physical last with his best powers. Which explains the condition of his legs when he was revived (they were still damaged).